# React, Component that edits the HTML of the next component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a strange case.
I must use a table library that has few features. There is no way to use `react-table` or more popular libraries.

I need the following feature => In the first column there are icons. If someone clicks on this icon, a new `<tr><td>xyz</td></tr>` should appear straight after this row.

It's a sort of tooltip, but instead of appearing on top of other content it should "add itself" between the row it has been triggered from and the next row.

I have no idea how to approach that.

The only things I have access to is the row index of the row the model was triggered from.

Is it feasible in React to create a component that somehow pushes a `<tr>` after the current `td` closes?

I am wondering if in react it's possible to manipulate HTML in a similar way, no matter if it is a bad practice...

Or maybe somehow running plain JavaScript is the only solution?

Any idea that helps me find a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, you are rendering the rows of the table based on some array with data (state?), could you push a new item into the array in the right position?

Comment: Theoretically yes, however that would be extremely complicated, since there are filters, sorting, a lot of fields, columns, redux. If I add something to the array, all the indexes of all the next rows will change and will break some functions.
This "tooltip" should not be added to the array, otherwise it will be "detected" by filters, sortings, etc.
It should be a row, but a "fake" row. Part of the HTML, but not part of the table logic.

Comment: Is it a problem if the fake row overlays the row below the selected one? I am going by the "tooltip" word here, thinking if the row could be just a div rendered in a portal and positioned appropriately using tools like floating UI (originally popper.js).